# How do I get past the Ocean in Candy Box 2?

Tags: candy-box-2

I'm jumping into the ocean in Candy Box and I just keep killing small fish, please help me.

I’ve got 387 hp, an enchanted naked monkey wizard staff, lightweight body armour, the octopus kings crown enchanted with obsidian, the red gloves and leather boots.

Answer (score 1):

You don't. The ocean is infinite.

There are several useful items to collect in the ocean but there is no end to it- eventually you need to leave or die.